# How to handle different types of one table?

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to create a database where a User can make a Post. There are different types of posts: A regular text post, a job post, product post, or question post.

I am trying to figure out the correct way of setting up my tables. I want each post to be able to be only one of the types. Whatever type it is, I want to connect it to the appropriate foreign table to retrieve the information necessary.

For example, if I want to make a job post, I want the post to be connected to a Job table. Likewise, if I have a question post, I want the Post to be connected to a Question table.

Do I have to create a connecting table for each type that I want? Or is there a way to make one connecting table for each type? Is there a way to create a Post_Type table?

Here is a diagram of what I am currently thinking it needs to look like

[image]

Comment: You can have separate tables for each type of post, in a inheritance-like structure. I would recommend this if you are sure there won't be any more types added regularly, since you would be hard coding the types in the structure. Also, is your business model supposed to accept abstract posts? That is, post without a specific subtype?

Comment: In your example each subtype has exactly the same properties. Maybe you don't need inheritance after all, and a single table will do.

Comment: Hi @TheImpaler! 

I would like there to be regular posts. That is, posts that focus on just the content of the Post. If there are external things associated with that post, be that a Product Job or Question, I would like to be able to retrieve those. 

I would be interested in a single table that could reference the specific Product, Job, or Question objects, but I am not sure what that would look like